# How can I create variables at run-time based on names pulled from a string?

Tags: javascript, string

I basically have the following string in the format:

```
A,B,C:D,E,F
```

What I am trying to achieve is a means of pairing up left hand side JavaScript variable, to the left of the ":" with the right hand side values to the right of the ":"

I would like to have the following variables set in, so that I can use in my coding, i.e:

```
var A = D;
var B = E;
var C = F;
```

I can then use the values of A,B and C as parameters into other JavaScript functions.

I have looked at the split and slice methods for this string manipulation but unsure how to pair up left hand side with right hand side values.

Comment: Note that if A == B (or == C) then you will wind up with naming conflicts, which would be problematic if D != E (or != F). You are better off doing `var x = D, y = E, z = F;` where x, y, z are fixed names.

Comment: @tonsils: are D, E and F intended to be variable names (as your code would seem to indicate), or string values?

Comment: Shog9, just to clarify, D,E and F here are actual values I want to assign to the left hand side variables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With this method (attaching variables to an object), you can reference variables in code without an eval statement.

```
a = "A,B,C:D,E,F";
array = a.split(":"); //split on the colon, get two strings
lefts = array[0];
rights = array[1];

obj = {} //object to attach variables to.
for( var i = 0; i < lefts.length; i++ )
{
  obj[lefts[i]] = rights[i]; //set the member variables of obj
}

obj.A // D
obj.B // E
obj.C // F
```

If you care about the wasted comma property, check if lefts[i] is equal to a comma before you set on the object.

Comment: Or obj['x'] when x is an invalid (or even valid) identifier.

Comment: Well... This does what it says, but also creates a "," property on `obj` (with a value of... ",").

Comment: This uses the **strings** "D", "E", and "F" as the right hand side. It doesn't actually assign the values of the **variables named** D, E and F, to the variables named A, B, C. What is it that the original poster wants?

Comment: My reading of the question yielded my implementation. It may or may not be what the OP was looking for, but it's what I read he's *asking* for.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, just to clarify, D,E and F here are actual values I want to assign to the left hand side variables.

Comment: Then my solution would work if you don't mind one that generates a code that you need to eval. If otherwise you already have an object whose fields you want to pair up, then you can modify it to do just that.

Comment: polygenelubricants, can you pls explain the eval side of things pls. What I basically want to achieve is to the pass the values assigned to A,B and C into other function calls.

Comment: @tonsils: try out my answer and see if it does what you need. I can help if you need further clarification.

Comment: polygenelubricants, that worked great but just realised that the value I currently have assigned to F is in the format of ":VAR1,VAL1" and b/c of split on ":" and ",", this is causing issues. Is there anyway to ignore after first ":" - Thanks.

Comment: polygenelubricant - also, now that I need to use the actual individual variables in other code, so can I just issue the command eval(pairup("A,B,C:D,E,F")); - is this correct? I need to access the individual variables.

Comment: The value of F itself shouldn't matter. Are you saying that the pairing formula string itself (`a` in your example) can contain multiple `:` and the left hand side and the right hand side may not have the same number of `,`?

Comment: actually, I can change the format of this so this is not an issue. I am now unsure how to evaluate and say access variable A alone - can you pls assist.

Comment: yes, that's what I mean by `eval` is that you can just take the returned string and just evaluate it. Returning the string also gives you a chance to figure out what it does and how it works if you need to modify it for your own need.

Comment: After you do `eval(pairup("A,B,C:D,E,F"))`, you can access `A` just as you would any other variable. I guess I'm not sure what your problem is.

Comment: Oh, so I can simply just do a alert(a); or pass a into another function - is this correct? I also assume that pairing is a global variable?

Comment: seems like it doesn't like the eval function call. I am getting an invalid character error - any ideas pls?

Comment: The code for `pairup` that I gave you declares `pairing` as a local variable. You can make it global, but I'm not sure why that'd be necessary.

Comment: The code for `pairup` I gave you uses uppercase V because that's what you used in your original question. Javascript is case-sensitive, so you'd want to use lowercase v instead if you're doing the `eval` approach.

Comment: Actually, changed that to lowercase var and added to the return part of your function return eval("pairing") but when I try to display the value of A, it's says that it's undefined.

Comment: If you want to evaluate inside `pairup`, then you just `eval(pairing);`, not `eval("pairing");`.

Comment: also tried your solution Stefan and also getting an undefined error.

Answer (score 0):

The `pairup` function here generates the code to do the pairing. You'd need to `eval` the returned code to actually execute it.

```
<script>

function pairup(s) {
  s = s.split(":");
  var lhs = s[0].split(",");
  var rhs = s[1].split(",");
  var pairing = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < lhs.length; i++) {
    pairing += "var " + lhs[i] + " = " + rhs[i] + "; \n";
  }
  return pairing;
}

alert(pairup("A,B,C:D,E,F"));

</script>
```

If you have the objects ready to bind the values of the variables too, then you can do something like this:

```
<script>

function pairup(s, oleft, oright) {
  s = s.split(":");
  var lhs = s[0].split(",");
  var rhs = s[1].split(",");
  for (var i = 0; i < lhs.length; i++) {
    oleft[lhs[i]] = oright[rhs[i]];
  }
}

oleft = {};
oright = { firstName: "F", lastName: "L" };
pairup("givenName,familyName:firstName,lastName", oleft, oright);
alert(oleft.givenName + ", " + oleft.familyName);

</script>
```