# Use value of a variable as name for another variable

Tags: javascript, string, node.js, variables

I have a function that uses an array to set names for different things

```
var settings = {
    slug: "foo"
}
```

Now, i want to create a variable, whitch name is the value of `settings.slug`, in this case `foo`

This obviously does not work:

```
var settings.slug = new Schema({
  title : String
, content   : String
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create variables at run-time based on names pulled from a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323602/how-can-i-create-variables-at-run-time-based-on-names-pulled-from-a-string)

Comment: @FelixKling i disagree, this question is about node.js, not client side javascript. And the question you link to doesn't have an answer I can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this is to use bracket notation and attach it to an existing object.  For example, you could make it a global variable by attaching it to the `global` object:

```
global[settings.slug] = new Schema({
  title   : String
, content : String
});

global['foo'];  // your Schema object
foo;  // automatically will cascade to the global window variable global['foo']
```

Comment: The OP uses node.js, where you would need to use `global` instead of `window` to access the global object

Comment: Ah, didn't notice.  Thanks for fixing that guys.

Answer (score 1):

```
this[settings.slug] = ...
```

This should work.

Comment: Awsome! I've gotta do a lot of writing before I know if it works, but thanks a bunch!

Comment: Would this work for calling the function as well? `var instance = new this[settings.slug]();`

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately. Are you aware of that this is node.js?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation):

```
someObj[settings.slug] = new Schema(...);

// equivalent to 
someObj["foo"] = ...
// or
someObj.foo = ...
```

However, you should not set properties of the `global` object imho. Use an extra namespace object if you need variable property names, but on the global object you are running the risk of overwriting some important globals.